# Is this a troll question?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357715/hard-drive-shutoff-when-closing-winxp-manually

OP's solution makes absolutely no sense at all to me.

> ive figured it out, i rewrote the whole thing in TCPIP and WingDings and once i caught the Kernel i asked him what to do, he said i need to IF(problem = oopsy) { do sums>0; algorithm++; 7=(n^6/12f(3.14-Maths.Py)); algorithm--; problem = almonds; } HardDrive.shutdown = True;

WingDings? Almonds?

Comment: Ah....could it be....

Comment: It's really taking all of my willpower not to upvote that

Comment: looooooooooooooooooool I love `problem = almonds`

Comment: -3 and closed *already* due to the meta effect :D

Comment: They are both new users Today (OP and Answer-er) - Chances are they are the same person trolling the community.

Comment: I think there are multiple trolls involved, unless the one grandmaster troll was powerful enough to create two seperate SO accounts... the clever bugger

Comment: @musefan a certain user has been able to create far more than 2 accounts for nefarious purposes recently. I'm talking 3 digits, from what I've heard. 2 accounts is nothing.

Comment: I wish that hadn't been deleted. That comment is a bit of a work of art.

Comment: I don't mean to devalue this post, but does it really need more upvotes than I have fingers?

Comment: Was there a dam that broke and flooded under the bridge? What are all the trolls doing out all of a sudden?

Comment: @CodyGray - troll mating season?  <shudder>

Comment: @musefan It wasn't my intention to get a bunch of upvotes for this, looking back at it, I asked an obvious question.

Comment: @musefan I think there's been a lot of ill will towards trolls lately. Entirely justified ill will.

Comment: @musefan you simply need more fingers. That's the actual problem.

Comment: @Stijn: No blame on you, I just think all those people have a strange understanding of when to upvote... or maybe it's me that doesn't understand how this metahole works. Seems the more time I spend here, the more it seems like "chat with rep"

Comment: It's just like everywhere else, @musefan. We have imaginary points, and they don't really matter.

Comment: @Bart: Are you donating yours?

Comment: Sure @musefan. As long as I can keep 10 of them, that's fine.

Comment: @Bart by "certain user" do you mean that guy from Bangladesh who's been IP-hopping actively and advertising their liVe onLine waTch foOtbaLL web$!T3, cost me 24+ hours of programming time and gained me 200 meta-rep in two days?

Comment: @CodyGray: Seems like there isn't much that really matters anymore. Sod it, i'm not even gonna leave my desk the next time I need to pee, what's the point

Comment: @JanDvorak Not to mention the helpful flag count shooting through the roof :P I was only here at the very end so I only managed to flag one or two :P

Comment: @Doorknob also, [43 accounts](http://stackexchange.com/users/233608/jan-dvorak?tab=accounts) of which most have 101 rep and a single bronze badge: `[citizen patrol]`

Comment: uh, oh. SF's just got a spam post. Now SU. Now webapps. Now more. Open your recent question feed guys, and update your copies of my userscript

Comment: @JanDvorak It's absolutely amazing how quickly this disappears now :O

Comment: Not on Meta, @musefan. People take this place too seriously. Srsly.

Comment: @Doorknob [13 seconds on the main site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360160/atletico-madrid-vs-barcelona-live-online). Not bad.

Comment: @JanDvorak I saw one on tex.SE, created an account, and in the 10 seconds it took me to do that it was already gone :O

Comment: @Doorknob sure, but I did manage the second one that got to tex

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like it's an attempt to get Hugh Mann (probably the same person as the OP) some free rep. I suspect sockpuppetry, but of course we can't be sure. The evidence is remarkably clear however, both users were created today, the question and the answer are nonsense, etc.

Fortunately, the community handles this kind of stuff very well. It's already deleted!

Comment: ... a bit like this question and answer then...

Comment: How do we know you didn't create them just to answer this question to get some free unicorn dollars? :-)

Comment: @musefan Heh, so much irony :D

Comment: @psubsee2003 How do we know you didn't create all the accounts involved in order to get comment upvotes?

Comment: Can you all just stop talking to yourselves.

Comment: @Asad I refuse to answer that question on the grounds that it may serve to incriminate me. ;-)

Comment: @psubsee2003 To whom? No-one here but your sockpuppets.

Comment: @Asad Eeeeeek! I've been finally outed as the puppet master :-)

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I wrote such awesome automatons that they could  start arguing between themselves!

Comment: @Bart same goes for you and Cody! ;)

Comment: @AsheeshR did you mean "between each other"? Arguing with oneself is a sign of a mental disease, especially if you do it aloud.